# Find groups of n elements with highest distance within all elements of the group in a matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, grouping

I have a matrix (pandas dataframe) with different identities where the values denote the distances between two identities:

```
     id1 id2 id3 id4
id1   0   1   3   2
id2   1   0   4   1
id3   3   4   0   2
id4   2   1   2   0
```

How can I find groups of `n` samples, where the distances between all identities within the groups are maximized? In other words, for each identity I want to find the group (identity + `(n-1)` other identities) that have the highest total distance of all pairs in the group.
With `n = 3` this would mean I have to check the following groups: `(id1, id2, id3), (id1, id2, id4), (id1, id3, id4), (id2, id3, id4)`. To check a group, all combinations would have to be calculated. For the first group this would mean to check the distances of `(id1, id2)=1, (id1, id3)=3 and (id2, id3)=4`. The total distance is `8`. I need a efficient way to calculate this for all identities since the original dataframe is 9000x9000. Luckily I only have to check for a fraction of the identities but against all possible identities (roughly 400x9000) where `n` can range from 3 to 8. The brute force attempt with just building the permutations and `n=3` would already mean having to check 121,459,503,000 combinations per identity, which is super inefficient.